# Difference between CAPABILITY_SUPPORT_HOLD and CAPABILITY_HOLD in android

Tags: android

I am working on a calling app on android. In the official documentation, there are two constants mentioned in [Call.Details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.Details)

CAPABILITY_SUPPORT_HOLD and CAPABILITY_HOLD

CAPABILITY_SUPPORT_HOLD has a description:

> Call can currently be put on hold or unheld.

CAPABILITY_HOLD has a description:

> Call supports the hold feature.

But it is quite confusing for me. Both are added in API level 23.

What is the difference between these two ? Any examples of when they should be used would be better.

Comment: I think you mixed up the documentation. Check it back. They are reversed actually, and the answer below is absolutely correct. You should mark it.

Comment: Yeah I got it @MARSK

Comment: Oh, there you are Perry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CAPABILITY_SUPPORT_HOLD` indicates whether the call generally supports the hold feature.

And `CAPABILITY_HOLD` indicates if the call can be currently put on hold - or unheld
 (as there may be situations where this may be temporarily not possible).